# C question: why is my 20 length string limits itself with 6 chars?

Tags: c, string, fgets

I am trying to make my own str_to_upper function but when i write something longer than 5 characters it only returns the first 5 chars and a '\0' char.
I guess word[5] should be '\0' and that means my code returns a 6 char length string but i don't understand where that '\0' comes from.

**my code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

char *str_to_upper(char *);

int main()
{
    char word[20];

    puts("Please enter a word: ");
    fgets(word, strlen(word), stdin);

    puts(str_to_upper(word));

    return 0;
}

char *str_to_upper(char *sentence)
{
    int length=strlen(sentence);

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
    {
        sentence[i]=toupper(sentence[i]);
    }

    return sentence;
}
```

**output:**

```
Please enter a word: 
aaaaaaaaaaa  
AAAAA
```

**when i put a for loop to write inside my array i get:**

```
Please enter a word:
aaaaaaaaaaa
AAAAA
AAAAA0��}y
```

Comment: You can use `strlen` only on a valid, null-terminated string to get its actual length. here: `fgets(word, strlen(word), stdin)`, `word` is uninitialized. `fgets` wants the size of the buffer it can fill, so use `sizeof(word)` here, which in your case is 20. (Your use in `strlen` in `str_to_upper` is good, though.)

Comment: Aside: `int length=strlen(sentence);

    for(int i=0; i<length; i++)` goes down `word` twice. Alternative: `for(int i=0; word[i]; i++)` or better `for(size_t i=0; word[i]; i++)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just substitute your

```
fgets(word, strlen(word), stdin);
```

with

```
fgets(word, sizeof(word), stdin);
```

In fact, `strlen` returns the length of a string (`word`) not initialized. So, current limit of `fgets` is a consequence of what you have in your stack.

Comment: Or simplify without `()`: `fgets(word, sizeof word, stdin);`